# Importing multiple 1D JSON arrays in Excel

Tags: json, excel, vba, powerquery

I'm trying to import a JSON file containing multiple unrelated 1D arrays with variable amount of elements into Excel.

The JSON I wrote:

```
{
    "table":[1,2,3],
    "table2":["A","B","C"],
    "table3":["a","b","c"]
    }
```

When I import the file using Power Query and expand the columns, it multiplies the previous entries each time I expand a new column.
[image]

Is there a way to show the elements of each array below each other and each array as a new column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to transform each `Record` into a `List` and then create a table using `Table.FromColumns` method.

This needs to be done from the Advanced Editor:

Read the code comments and explore the Applied Steps to better understand.
Also HELP topics for the various functions will be useful

```
let

//Change following line to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\New Text Document.txt")),

//Get Field Names (= table names)
    fieldNames = Record.FieldNames(Source),

//Create a list of lists whereby each sublist is derived from the original record
    jsonLists = List.Accumulate(fieldNames,{}, (state, current)=> state & {Record.Field(Source,current)}),

//Convert the lists into columns of a new table
    myTable = Table.FromColumns(
        jsonLists,
        fieldNames
    )
in
    myTable
```

***Results***
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved my issue completely